# Stuff-A-Way swag held by customs and they want a detailed list of the content

Tags: support, swag

DHL says the Stuff-A-Way package is held by customs (in Germany). As suggested in this [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/325381/stuff-a-way-swag-held-by-customs) I told them that any duties and taxes should be handled by Stack Exchange.

They now wrote me back that they need more information. They want me to provide:

- a detailed description of the package's content
- how much every single item is worth

They say after 4 days they will bill (me?) for every day that they hold the package, there is a base fee and also a per item fee if it is more than 3 items.

How should I proceed here?

<del>I don't know the exact contents or how much it is worth.</del> 
Update: I just saw that there is an attachment that includes a scan of an invoice with items and price. I will copy that information to their other form and see how it goes. Their forms are a bit confusing though, so any tips how I should declare the shipment are appreciated.

I'm also not sure how duties/taxes will be handled. Stack Exchange is not mentioned anywhere on any document - invoice and sender is by "STEX (PRINTEX) INC", so I'm not sure if they know who to bill.

Update: DHL now requested an order confirmation that shows the value of each single item and which includes information about package(s), sender and receiver. They say they don't accept invoices as proof of the good's value. Unfortunately I couldn't yet get any response from Printex.

Comment: I emailed JNat in a reply to the initial Swag away email yesterday for a list of stuff I was sent for the same reason as you (UK). I am still waiting on a reply.

Comment: Just to keep you updated I have had a reply from JNat stating _"Will check with our vendor and let you know ASAP."_

Comment: Same situation here, in India.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is a pretty unusual situation, from my past experience with swag-related endeavors... The fact that all the boxes are different for each user complicates issues, and means I can't just post an answer here everyone with this problem can use...

In any case... **anyone else experiencing this, please email me. I'll then put you in touch with our vendor directly and they should be able to help you.**

Comment: FWIW I just received my swag despite DHL asking this question of me, will give them a ring and update when I find out exactly what is going on.

Comment: Huh... well, I forwarded your info to our vendor anyway, so they should get in touch with you shortly.

Comment: Further updates, I called DHL, they just wanted to know the "split" price of the items to clear it through customs as they had a total but not a split for each "category". After having spoken to someone and listing what I received they have said that they can do it so nothing is left to sort my end. Therefore, all that is left to say is a big thank you to SE for the help in this and a massive thank you for the swag!

Comment: @TheLethalCoder thanks for your updates! I hope it will be the same for me. They apparently already have a detailed invoice with individual costs of each item, so I'm not sure why they asked me for it again though.

Comment: On a side note to this, I received an email from Printex with the items that were sent to me. I noticed that one of the items was _"New Mens Stack Overflow T-shirts Large"_ but I did not receive a SO t-shirt in the swag. A quick email cleared this up that they were out of stock (as expected) and I would not be receiving one. This is more to let others know in case they are waiting for another delivery that they are probably out of stock. (On a side side note I was sure I selected SE t shirt on the form not SO but it doesn't really matter). Thanks again SE!

Comment: Hey, I just received an email from DHL asking for various sorts of documents. I have already provided them my proof of identity so that's not what they want this time. The shipment is being held in customs and they want a bill or receipt. I have sent you an email as well. Please check!

Comment: @Yashovardhan For me there was an invoice attached to the email from DHL. They now requested an order confirmation that shows the value of each item. @ JNat I have also sent you an email

Comment: @kapex Yeah same, even I got the invoice but they want more details.

Comment: @JNat Need some help here, too. DHL is asking for the content of the box, Sent you one email, please do the needful.

Comment: Thanks again for your help JNat, the DHL tracking page says the package has arrived!